# SQL Server Linux - OLE DB not registered when using OPENROWSETsql

Tags: sql-server, linux, t-sql, oledb

The error from my DB: `SQL Error [7403] [S0001]: The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.`

How do I install these SQL Server drivers on Linux? So far I've only seen Windows examples.

Comment: I don't think you can use a COM-based OLE DB provider on Linux.

Comment: @Dan Guzman How would I go about using OPENROWSET to load an xlsx on Linux then? The provider/driver that uses is Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 - is there an alternative?

Comment: @Larnu I already have the ODBC drivers installed, I'm missing the OLEDB drivers.